# aws cli query to find the last snapshot taken, the date it was taken, the tag used if any, the name tag of the instance and the instance i.d

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I need to get 5 colums reported from awscli. These are, last snapshot taken for instance, the date it was taken, the tag used if any, the name tag of the instance and the instance i.d.

The below will list ALL snapshots and the time taken and a 'null' name gets reported...

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].{ID:SnapshotId,Time:StartTime,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value}'
```

This will give me the description of the snapshot, the snap id and the date:

```
 aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --output json | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime < "'$(date --date='-1 month' '+%Y-%m-%d')'") | [.Description, .StartTime, .SnapshotId]'
```

So basically I have something that gives me the snapshot data, will query on date and tell me what time it was taken but I'm missing the full requirement all in one.

I guess the main stumbling block for me is how to only report on the last snapshot that was taken for an instance. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [sort_by](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html) get the latest snapshot.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots  --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].{SnapshotId:SnapshotId,StartTime:StartTime}"
```

output

```
{
    "SnapshotId": "snap-123456", 
    "StartTime": "2020-07-07T13:57:05.982Z"
}
```

OR if you just looking for owned by you then

```
MY_ACCOUNT_ID=1234567 aws ec2 describe-snapshots  --filter "Name=owner-id,Values=$MY_ACCOUNT_ID" --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].{SnapshotId:SnapshotId,StartTime:StartTime}"
```

[aws-snapshot-by-me](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet/blob/master/aws-snapshot.md)

**Update:**

As the above query does not contain instance information, so you can get instance information by doing a reverse query. find snapshot first and then find instance ID using attached volume ID.

```
VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=owner-id,Values=$MY_ACCOUNT_ID"  --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].VolumeId" --output text)
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filter "Name=volume-id,Values=$VOLUME_ID" --query 'Volumes[?Attachments != `null`].Attachments[].InstanceId'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! It only seems to return the latest snapshot taken across the account... what I was hoping to get was the latest snapshot for each instance... so - list out, say, all 100 instances, and then each instance may have 10 snapshots over 10 days bu I would only wish to find the latest one for each

Comment: Does adding a star, like this display all of the snapshots taken for all instances? aws ec2 describe-snapshots  --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[*].{SnapshotId:SnapshotId,StartTime:StartTime}"

Comment: then you definitely need something else query, it does not contain instance info

Comment: Hi thanks for this - the first line doesn't produce any output. VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=owner-id,Values=$MY_ACCOUNT_ID"  --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].VolumeId" --output text) I'm copying and pasting as is, and also I am hard coding my account i.d. I am also using * instead of -1 still no output is returned. I have a lot of snapshots so that is strange.

Comment: the output is assinged to varaible, you need to echo variable. or try `aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=owner-id,Values=123456788" --query "sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime`